# How do I add single line at the end of each page on SSRS report builder?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, reportbuilder3.0

**info**: I have a simple tablix and at the end of each group it generates new page.

**I want** to add a line at the end of each page.

--> [explanation image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y4PzE.png)

**I tried**: 1) add footer top border and 2) add a line (report item).

Why the line changes place?

Does it has to do with tablix size or page size?

Then why by adding footer top border has the same result with adding a single line element?

Comment: If you place the line in the footer, then it cannot come up high next to the tablix. Have you tried exporting your report or printing it to see where the line actual is?

Comment: I tried. It seems good on pdf exports! But, on Report Builder the line's position I think depends on the size of the tablix.